# Why does passing collection to filters in Ruby on Rails break the rake db:migrate task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, activeadmin

In my ActiveAdmin application, I have a resource page which is actually a renamed resource as follows:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Entity, as: 'Report' do
  menu label: 'Reports', parent: 'Administration', priority: 2

  filter  :region
  filter  :country,   collection:   Country.all.sort_by(&:display_name)
  filter  :city,      collection:   City.all.sort_by(&:display_name)
  filter  :model,     collection:   Model.all.sort_by(&:display_name)

  ...  

  index as: :block, download_links: false do |entity|
    ...
  end

end
```

I found that if I set the `collection: ...` the `rake db:migrate` breaks with the following message:

```
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Table 'myapp-develop.countries' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `countries`
```

Can anyone explain why does this happen and how could I work around it?